# When is using ~+ useful?

Tags: bash, zsh, ksh

As I understand it, `~+` means the same thing as "the current working directory".

So `echo ~+` should print the same as `pwd`.

What is the purpose of this tilde expansion `~+` ?

Comment: It's not as portable compared to `$PWD`.

Comment: `~-` works as well...

Comment: @polemon, `~-` only works if you haven't already run `pushd`.  It means the last directory in the stack, not the first.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Didn't even know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there for completeness.

You could use it as a shorter form of `$PWD`.  You save a whole two keystrokes!

Comment: I save three with my keyboard layout :)